# What does "elements (of)" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> When the teaching and testing implications of No Child Left Behind Act
> of 2001 finally reached the classroom, there was a flurry of student
> resistance. Fifty-eight students at Danvers High School in
> Massachusetts signed a petition against being required to take the
> Massachusetts Comprehensive Assessment System (MCAS) exam, and those
> who refused to sit for the test were suspended from school. Students
> at other high schools in the state joined them. What might be called
> “**elements** of refusal” popped up throughout the country: large numbers
> of Michigan students opted out of the Michigan Educational Assessment
> Test, and Wisconsin’s high school “exit exam” (a condition of
> graduation) was scrapped owing to massive resistance from parents and
> students.

I suspect that the word "elements" here means "a small but significant presence of a feeling or abstract quality" (OED, definition 1.1) and can be replaced with synonyms such as "trace(s)" or "hint(s)". Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion isn't completely wrong, but "resistance" here isn't really a "feeling or abstract quality", because the resistance was specific concrete actions.  I think a more appropriate definition might be

> a distinct group within a larger group or community

([definition 2c here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/element))

The larger community was "students affected by No Child Left Behind", and the distinct groups were the students at Danvers High School, the large numbers of Michigan students who opted out of the Michigan Educational Assessment Test, the students and parents who resisted in Wisconsin, etc.